# GridView Won't Display

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

The data table is returning the correct amount of rows/records.But for some reason I can not get my GridView to Render..nothing displays at all...........

**EDIT:** The GridView returns "RowErorrs" and "Has Errors" columns. but not my data.

```
Dim ConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oakfratintdbConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [OFCInterments]", Conn)

Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim DT As New DataTable
'WHERE ([FirstName] = @FirstName)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "Mike")


Try
    Conn.Open()
    DA.SelectCommand = cmd
    DA.Fill(DT)
    GridView1.DataSource = DT
    GridView1.DataBind()

    If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim NoResultsText As String = DT.Rows.Count.ToString + " records found."
        txtStatys.Text = NoResultsText
        txtStatys.Visible = True


    End If


Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
Finally
    Conn.Close()
    DA.Dispose()
    Conn.Dispose()


End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

> The GridView returns "RowErorrs" and "Has Errors" columns. but not my data.

That is not a property of the `GridView` but of the `DataTable`.

[`DataTable.HasErrors` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.haserrors.aspx)

You can use [`DataTable.GetErrors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.geterrors.aspx) to retrieve a `DataTable` with all row errrors. Inspect the [`RowError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowerror.aspx) property of each `DataRow` and you know the reason for the exception. You can do that all in a debugger [quick-watch-window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx).

---

A few points you should take into account:

GridView is not dispayed, some possible reasons:

- Is the GridView visible at all(and all of it's parents because it inherits the property)?
- have you registered the `RowDataBound` event and an uncaught exception there?

general suggestions:

- Don't use a `Catch` block just to rethrow the exception(even `Throw` alone would be better since it would keep the stacktrace). Instead don't catch it or do something useful with it(f.e. logging).
- use the [`Using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to dispose your ADO.NET objects like the connection(closes it implicitely)

Comment: Using a Breakpoint...The "HasErrors" property is remaing "false" throughout the entire process.

Comment: Where have you set the breakpoint, on this line `DA.Fill(DT)`? Then you can execute this line in the debugger. You have edited your question and mentioned that the grid returns "HasErrors". What does that mean, where have you seen it?

Comment: My Gridview renders"RowError" and "HasErrors"  columns.

Comment: Ok, but these values are coming from the underlying DataTable and not from the GridView. Perhaps you should also show us the aspx markup with the columns. Do you have `AutoGenerateColumns=true`?